# android: ScrollView parent can't resolve the weight

Tags: android, scrollview

I have a weird issue. As you can see in my code below, for `hor_Ln`I have set the `android:layout_weight` to 50, therefore it should fits 50% of height of the screen to fill button's height also, however it does not.

Although if I change the `ScrollView` to `LinearLayout` as parent layout, it seems original and correct.

Here is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_width="match_parent">


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/vertical_Ln"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="100"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/hor_Ln"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="10"
            android:layout_weight="50">

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="5"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />


        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Here is the output:

[image: Picture]

What is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to include property `android:fillViewport="true"` to make your `ScrollView` full screen.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback but it does not Scroll When its child cross over the screen's height

Comment: Sorry @ShahinSoft I didn't understand. What you want to achieve?

Comment: oh , I think you are right , I figure it out Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In xml set  android:fillViewport="true"

```
    <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true" >
   <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/vertical_Ln"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="100"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/hor_Ln"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="10"
        android:layout_weight="50">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="5"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />


    </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

  </ScrollView>
```